# Remove horizontal scroll bar if no data exists in datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a tree-view and datagridview on my form.

I will have an import option through which I can import txt files. When I select a particular file I will add it as a node to the tree-view and the data in that file will be displayed in the datagridview.

I will also have a context menu that has some options such as Close which will be displayed on Tree-view right click. If I select Close I will clear all the Nodes of tree-view and clear all rows of the datagridview.

But the horizontal scroll bar is not getting cleared can any one tell how to clear this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to clear the columns of the datagridview

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```

and before adding new rows. need to add columns using

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column_Name", "Header_Text");
```

Comment: But when i tried to add new record it is showing the error as No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.

Comment: you need to add Columns using dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column_Name", "Header_Text"); before u add rows. edited the post.

Comment: I already added columns by default to the control from Column property

Comment: Scrollbar is shown because the column width is greater than width of the DataGridView. so if you dont want to display the horizontal scrollbar, you have two options; 1) by clearing the columns and adding it again 2) you can set the columnwidth to zero or less than DataGridView width.